# Why is my Ubuntu box shutting itself off?

Tags: 12.10, shutdown

I just built a relatively cheap Ubuntu box for use as a home server.  I had a monster headache getting my Win 8 machine to talk to it via samba, but this is beside the point.

I've now been attempting to transfer large amounts of media across the network to store on my home server and it keeps shutting itself off.  I have set the "when to suspend" option in the power settings to "never" and it's still doing it.  It doesn't even seem to offer any warning.  It's behind me right now as I type this post and I'll just hear that "power down" sound (all the fans spinning down, etc.) and it's off.  When I turn it back on, it goes straight from POST to the login screen, so I'm guessing this is some manner of suspend/hibernate behavior.  And... it just did it again.  This is getting really frustrating.

Anybody know of anything else I can check?  I'm praying it isn't a hardware failure.  I just bought the stuff.

Comment: any heat problem?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm not sure in Ubuntu where to monitor temp, but I did watch the CPU usage and it never exceeded 40% on either core.  Also, as I commented on an answer below, it seems to be fine now that I'm not transferring large amounts of data.

Comment: In my case this happened due to graphic card over heat problem, this might be a hard dis over heat in your case ;)

Comment: That's possible.  I have no video card installed (AMD APU so graphics are on-die).  But HDD could be maybe?  It's a cheap WD 5400 RPM deal.

Comment: Install the lm-sensors package and the command sensors should report some temperatures of interest.

Comment: Thank you, @ubfan1.  I will do that.  I tried installing a package an hour or so ago (plex media server) and it shut down right in my face, with zero warning.  So the problem is definitely not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a power supply issue. I would try looking at some of the logs in `/var/logs/`. There might be a clue. Maybe as soon as something happened a shutdown signal is seen. Who knows? See how it runs with the bare minimum peripherals. Unplug everything you can and try to narrow down the problem. Since it's a custom build it might be consuming more power than you expected.

Comment: I was worried about that.  Where would I find the relevant logs?  Sorry, I've been using various 'nix distros over the years, but I'm far from the power user I am on other, lesser, systems.

Comment: I edited my post. Google knows the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I will check the logs and see what I can see.  I don't think it's a _lack_ of power, because I actually bought a larger power supply than this machine should ever need.  What's interesting is that now that the file transfers are complete, it seems to be having no troubles.  So... the transfer is the cause?  I monitored CPU usage and it never exceded 40% on either core.